# Hide message "No video with supported format and MIME type found" on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I show the video tag with attribute src is empty and add src later.
But the firefox show the message "No video with supported format and MIME type found" before i add src to the video tag.

How can i hide the message?

Comment: Don't know if that's what are you looking for, but you may just simply hide (`display: none`) the `<video>` and display it after adding `src`.

Comment: @KrzysztofDziembała thank you, but i want the video showing while loading src, so i cant hide it.